# JasperStarter DB connection issues

Tags: jdbc, mysql-8.0, jasperstarter

I am trying to run the following command:

```
/opt/jasperstarter/bin/jasperstarter pr --db-url jdbc:mysql://apps:@192.168.0.232:3306/zinc?useSSL=false \
                                        -f pdf \
                                        -p Y5Ni%234MAC5nosAyEv6B7dEQE%21iMoC%40 \
                                        -o /vagrant/ASB5ff7844ac8ae7 /vagrant/project/templates/pdf/jasper/erp-invoice-workorders.jasper \
                                        -P ID_ORGANIZATION=632 ID_INVOICE=92214 JASPER_DIR='/vagrant/project/templates/pdf/jasper'
```

It's not erroring - it's producing a PDF but the values are all NULL so it's clearly not connecting to the database.

Here are the original switches (sans the `--db-url`) which produce an error:

```
-t mysql \
-u apps \
-H 192.168.0.232 \
--db-port 3306 \
-n zinc \
```

The error is pretty obvious:

> WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity
> verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+
> and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default
> if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing
> applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set
> to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting
> useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server
> certificate verification. Unable to connect to database: Access denied
> for user 'apps'@'192.168.1.241' (using password: YES)

I'm at a loss on what I am doing wrong. JasperStarter doesn't have a "disable SSL" switch, so they recommend specifying that option in the DB URL `?useSSL=false` which I've done but nothing is happening?!?

I've tried placing the passwords, etc inside the DB URI in all various combos with the same results.

I'm not sure if this is a JasperStarter issue or something trivial in the connection string I'm missing, any thoughts or suggestions?

EDIT | I am curious as to whether I have to install JDBC drivers, now that I am using the DB-URI instead of explicit command switches? Internally, wouldn't the binary use that anyway, so how has this worked for all these years, but now because I am using `--db-uri` its required?

The commands I have in the vagrant file to install jasperstarter:

```
#  JasperStarter start
sed -i "s/stretch main/stretch main non-free contrib/g" /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update && apt-get -y install msttcorefonts

cd /tmp
cp /vagrant/.java/jasperstarter-3.0.0.zip   jasperstarter-3.0.0.zip
unzip jasperstarter-3.0.0.zip
mv jasperstarter /opt;
cd /opt/jasperstarter/bin
chmod 777 *
ln -s  /usr/share/java/mysql.jar  /opt/jasperstarter/jdbc/mysql.jar
apt-get install -y default-jre
# JasperStarter end
```

Comment: The _Access denied for user 'apps'@'192.168.1.241'_ message suggests you either have the wrong password for user "apps", or user "apps" has not been configured (on the MySQL server) to accept connections originating from host 192.168.1.241 (i.e. your client machine). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362535/1045-access-denied-for-user-rootip-address-using-password-yes-in-py) for a similar issue. Each user ID has to be enabled for each remote host's name/IP (or it has to use the wildcard `%` for "any host"). I would check this first, before looking into SSL issues.

Comment: It looks to me like you should use `--db-url jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.232:3306/zinc?useSSL=false -u apps -p Y5Ni%234MAC5nosAyEv6B7dEQE%21iMoC%40` instead of trying to specify the username and an **empty password** in the url.

Comment: I think I tried that combination but will try again. I’m pretty sure it’s an issue with JasperStarter. Connection with explicit switches works on a MariaDB but not on mysql. I’ll figure it out